# PHP script not working every time

Tags: php

I have a page which contains a form. I'm passing it's data through AJAX to a PHP script which does something in background and I'm returning a JSON encoded array.

`{"type": , "user":, "loginKey":}`

Type is something from 1 to 3, user it's user's name and loginKey is created by a function.

PHP does the following: gets user's input, sanitizes it, check if user exists in database by counting rows. If there is a user in the database runs the following hashing algorithm

```
function hashing($user, $pass, $mail){
    $pass=md5($pass);
    $pass=md5($pass.$user);
    $pass=md5($pass.$mail);
    return $pass;
}
```

Data is passed back to my function, checks if hash's value corresponds to that in database, then proceeds to create a loginKey

```
$key=md5($pass.date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

Where `$pass` is the hashed value we got from our function.
After this, it updates my database with this new `loginKey` and finally returns it to be printed in my JSON encoded array.

The problem here is that my function is not always working. Sometimes it returns 0 even if it updates the loginKey in database with a good value (after updating there is only `return $key;`).

**Resolved**

I changed hashes from `MD5` to `password_hash()` with `Argon2` hash type and now it is working every time. Seems like there was a bug with md5 hashing as I did not change anything else in my code.

Comment: You should not use `md5()` for storing passwords. As for the issue, have you tried reproducing the error manually, so you can cause it to happen and threby dumping out the values of the variables when it does to see where the code falls down?

Comment: `md5()` is nowhere near secure enough for this kind of stuff. Check out `password_hash()` instead of rolling your own crypto!

Comment: As this was a project for my school, I was not looking into deep securing it. Why it's not working concerns me.
I will also keep your advice and I'm looking right now in `password_hash()`. Thank you for that!

Comment: You need to post the part of the code that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**

I changed hashes from MD5 to password_hash() with Argon2 hash type and now it is working every time. Seems like there was a bug with md5 hashing as I did not change anything else in my code.

Comment: `password_hash` and `password_verify` are a good secure choice.